# How to make WndProc inline?

Tags: windows, winapi, inline, wndproc, winmain

Is it possible, and if so, how to make WndProc inline?

That is, I would like to process Windows messages WM_... within WinMain,
so as to avoid seemingly needless function calls.

Thank you.

Comment: If a window procedure could be inlined, what should `GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` return? Or how would you propose the system should implement various hooks without an actual call? Now really, this sounds like premature optimization. Particularly with UI code, where the bottleneck is the user, never the code.

Comment: `WndProc` this is callback, called by system. you anyway must pass to system some address of function, which will be called

Comment: Why do you feel that these function calls are a problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because I wish to create an optimal 3D [animation] app, for a relatively weak setup (Intel(R) Core i5(TM)-2520M 8gb ram, integrated graphics), and eliminate constant calls to WM_PAINT from WinMain via `DispatchMessage()` every `SetTimer()` tick, but, as suspected (and according to answer by @IInspectable), it seems to be restricted by design.

Comment: But the function call overhead is not a limiting factor. You've misdiagnosed that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I see what you mean, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inline a window procedure. This is by design.

You can easily see the architectural limitation when registering a window class. This is done by calling [RegisterClassExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw), passing along a [WNDCLASSEXW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) structure. That structure requires a valid `lpfnWndProc`. You cannot take the address of an inlined function.

There are other aspects that require the window procedure to be an actual function. For example, the stored window procedure address serves as a customization point and allows [subclassing controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview), e.g. to tweak the behavior of a standard control.

There's nothing you can do to avoid the function call. If you want to limit the scope of variables, you can assign the result of a lambda expression to the `lpfnWndProc` member. Visual Studio makes sure to synthesize the correct function signature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, pretty much what I suspected having programmed for Windows for quite a few years (non-professionally though). My intent (as I also mentioned in replying to a comment under the post) was to optimize 3D graphics, which is recomputed and redrawn every `SetTimer()` tick, hence WM_PAINT is called 5-50 times/sec (fps) depending on the scene. And so it felt natural, that aside from optimizing algorithms involved, it would make sense to eliminate as many jumps/call+ret as possible.

Comment: Just to put the perspective straight, a function call fades into statistical noise when compared to a *single* heap allocation. Besides, the GPU and CPU operate in parallel. While the GPU is busy presenting the current frame, the CPU usually prepares the data for the next frame. More often than not, the CPU is idling away, waiting for the GPU to finish things up. Optimizing a function call on the CPU merely allows it to idle a few cycles longer.